# How to use plugin PDFViewer in cordova

Tags: cordova, plugins

I write an app in cordova, and want to open pdf file. 
I used plugin 
https://github.com/cdibened/PDFViewer
by use command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-pdf-viewer
```

And then, i called this plugin by the same in documentation

```
PDFViewer.openPDF(url);
```

But it's not open the file. i don't know why and how to debug this.
And [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N5sBtqki2mJYY-GE2-yLaoWyWRB3X5Zy) is my project. 
Thanks for your helps!

Comment: some body can help me?

Comment: What is the url of the PDF? If you open your browser and go that url via the console, what do you see? If you place the pdf in your root and use PDFViewer.openPDF("myfile.pdf"); in the browser console, what do you see?

Comment: This is my pdf document: http://workwiththanh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Day-con-lam-giau-tap-11.pdf
But when i open by  PDFViewer.openPDF("that url"), it show me like this "cannot openPDF of undefined". I had uploaded my project in post. Can you help me please!

Comment: Looks like the plugin is not properly loaded, hence the 'undefined' warning.
This PDFviewer plugin you mentioned is more than 2 years old, you can also try cordova-plugin-file-opener2 which has more recent updates and examples.